# Can't configure Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

In our Jenkins pipeline setup, I am only able to view configuration for Repo and Branch level.  Scan Multibranch Pipeline Triggers is set for 1 day.  I think because of this setting Scan periodically starts rebuilding all the BitBucket pull requests when it sees changes on the source branch.  I want to disable this auto-building somehow, configuration settings are not an option.  Even though I am an administrator on Jenkins with full power, I get the following message when I view configuration "username missing the Job/Configure permission" . Is there any way to fix this setting or something I can do in the Jenkinsfile to prevent building PRs every time there is a new MultiBranch Pipeline scan.